# List view is broken after applying jslink

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

I used client side rendering on a list view to override how the items inside it should be rendered.

The javascript:

```
var overrideContext = {};
overrideContext.BaseViewID = 3;
overrideContext.ListTemplateType = 951325;
overrideContext.Templates = {};
overrideContext.Templates.Header= renderHeader;
overrideContext.Templates.Item  = renderItem;
overrideContext.Templates.Footer = renderFooter;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
```

The view:

```
<View BaseViewID="3" DisplayName="Overzicht" Type="HTML" SetupPath="Pages\ViewPage.aspx" Url="Overzicht.aspx">
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <JSLink Default="TRUE">~siteCollectionLayouts/RenderSummary.js</JSLink>
    <Toolbar Type="FreeForm" Position="After" />
    ....
</View>
```

The rendering works if the view is embedded in another page, but if you visit the list and select the view to which the jslink is applied errors occur:

```
Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls+UnsafeControlException: Een webonderdeel of besturingselement voor een webformulier op deze pagina kan niet worden weergegeven of geïmporteerd. Het type is niet gevonden of staat niet als veilig geregistreerd.
[Translates as: a webpart or usercontrol for the form on this pages can not be found or imported. The type can not be found or is not registered as safe.]
at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls.GetTypeFromGuid(Boolean isAppWeb, Guid guid, Guid solutionId, Nullable`1 solutionWebId, String assemblyFullName, String typeFullName, Boolean throwIfNotSafe)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)

Application error when access /Lists/Nieuws/Overzicht.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartResultSet.get_PartOrder()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)
```

Does anyone have an idea what I could try to change to get the view page displaying as well?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the error was not caused by using the jslink but rather by a missing 'WebPartZoneID' attribute on the view definition. The following fixed it:

```
<View BaseViewID="3" DisplayName="Overzicht" WebPartZoneID="Main" Type="HTML" SetupPath="Pages\ViewPage.aspx" Url="Overzicht.aspx">
```